# pm2 keys bad permission on gitlab-ci

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci, pm2

I would like run pm2 from gitlab-ci runner, but after run pm2, i've this message :

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xxxxxxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/root/.ssh' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/root/.ssh": bad permissions
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Deploy failed
```

I've try to set `chmod 600 ~/.ssh` but not result.

Anyone can help me ?